# Drawing a line in the direction a player is moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

For debugging purposes I am trying to draw 2 debug lines. One in the direction that the character is facing and one in the direction that the character is moving.

I have the following function that is called in the update method.

```
    void DrawDirectionLines()
    {
        var wishDir = transform.position + transform.forward;
        var movementDir = Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity).eulerAngles;

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.forward * 5, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + movementDir * 5, Color.blue);
    }
```

The red direction debug line works perfectly however the blue line representing the actual movement direction of the player seems to always misbehave and never points in the direction the player is moving in.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your movemendDir is a Vector3 with the euler angles, and not a direction vector.

The good news is that [rb.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) is the direction you only need. The documentation says: *Unity velocity also has the speed in X, Y, and Z defining the direction.*

But if you use that velocity vector the lenght of the line will depends on the velocity. The solution is [normalize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html) that vector.

You need to replace:

```
var movementDir = Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity).eulerAngles;
```

to:

```
var movementDir = rb.velocity.normalized;
```